# PHP Undefined index: REDIRECT_STATUS - error 404

Tags: htaccess, php, apache, 404

Custom 404 page in PHP using .htaccess file.
If page dosen't exist redirect to error.php.
I don't know why but it doesn't work. `Notice: Undefined index: REDIRECT_STATUS on line 2`

```
<?php 
$error = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"];
$ettor_title = '';
$error_message = '';
    if($error == 404) {
        $ettor_title = '404 Page Not Found';
        $error_message = 'The document/file requested was not found on this server';
    }
    ?>
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $ettor_title; ?></h1>
        <h5><?php echo $error_message; ?></h5>
    </body>
    </html>
```

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://doamin.com/error.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 https://doamin.com/error.php
> ```

You need to use a root-relative URL-path, not an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive. If you specify an absolute URL then it will trigger a 302 redirect to the error document (and a 200 OK response when the error document is served) and consequently, any information about the request that caused the error (such as `REDIRECT_STATUS` and `REDIRECT_URL` etc.) is lost - which is what's happening here.

A root-relative URL-path results in an *internal subrequest* and a 404 response from Apache. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

*Aside:*

> ```
> $error = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"];
> ```

However, you should *always* test that the variable exists before using it. If the error document is requested directly (which is essentially what's happening above) then `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not set. For example:

```
$error = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] ?? null;
```

Comment: `root-relative URL-path` that was my problem. Thank you very much for your help.